# Do you need to format a flash drive before dd an image to it?

Tags: partitioning, formatting, dd, img

Does dd or Windows Image Writer work regardless whether the target device was formatted or partitioned correctly?

I'm trying to flash a Chromium OS build to a USB flash drive following [these instructions](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/).

Comment: No you don't need to see this: https://superuser.com/questions/1199344/dd-to-a-different-filesystem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes (you don't need to partition the drive). When you write directly to a block device (`/dev/sdX`) with `dd`, you are overwriting any partition table currently on the drive.

I haven't ever used (or heard of) Windows Image Writer, but if it's similar to dd, it writes raw data to the drive, regardless of what was present before.

Comment: This answer is wrong, see this: https://superuser.com/questions/1199344/dd-to-a-different-filesystem